# Would Docker or Vagrant be help in creating test machine for our enterprise product

Tags: java, vagrant, docker

I am working on a enterprise product and primarily there are 3 pieces to it swing based client, DB, Server(for now we can ignore DB part). Being enterprise product Client and Server comes with their own installer(it is not like configuring apache or JBOSS and deploy war's on it).

We have CI configured to generate the nightly OS specific builds for Client and server which can be installed.

So we have to test these build regularly on specific OS, which requires a lot of manual process of installing and creating system with X version client on Y OS OR X version server on Y OS. This is becoming very tedious since we are all on windows and doing next-> next -> really sucks(I have created a script which installed our product via shell but then it is still steps which I believe can be automated, but don't how). And also we need an isolation.

Now I am thinking how can we automate this process of creating these test machine. I have just started exploring Vagrant/Docker if they can be helpful to me (and under the their concept, still doesn't understand Puppet/Chef though) and I am confused in which strategy should I adopt

1. Create VM via vagrant and run my installation script on that box (This will require one VM per Client or per server)
2. Create VM via vagrant and run my client docker containers on it (this I guess, will require one VM for multiple client or server, since they would be under container)

Note: I have to create VM, since we are on window.either via vagrant or via boot2docker

So my question are

1. If these 2 strategy are valid and not wrong then out of these 2 which strategy should I adopt out of two ?
2. Are there any different strategy that I am missing or am I approaching this in right way ?
3. If strategy #2 is to be adopted then how can I create container/docker images in which my client is installed

Answer (score 1):

> > > how can I create container/docker images in which my client is installed

You must put in a Dockerfile all what you do in order to have your client started and configured.

In order to do so, you can either create a container, do all the stuff, and then `docker commit` or the better way is to put all the required commands in a Dockerfile, so that when you do a slight modification, you build a new version easily with a basic `docker build -t myclient_version_n .`

Check the docs

- https://docs.docker.com/examples/mongodb/#creating-a-dockerfile-for-mongodb

and how to automate builds

- http://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#automated-builds

how to create a Dockerfile

- https://docs.docker.com/examples/nodejs_web_app/#creating-a-dockerfile

and have a look at existing Dockerfiles of containerized application in the docker Hub

- https://registry.hub.docker.com/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Vagrant would be to use Docker Machine.  You could leverage the cloud providers as @m1keil mentioned too.  Machine can provision Docker hosts on a number of providers and they are ready to go.

Disclosure: I work at Docker and am the maintainer of Machine :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your strategies seem valid to me. The addition of containers (docker) to your process might help you speed up and parallelize the testing process (if it's fully automatic testing) since the initialization time and the general resource consumption of a container are lower. However one cannot give you definitive answer without inspecting your testing process first. And since you haven't provided any details about it, it would be hard to tell you if you should use the first or the second strategy.
2. You can take advantage of the cloud and use services such as AWS, Azure, GCE, etc to initialize machines and run your tests. You can use Vagrant to do this, or skip Vagrant and create your own simple scripts by using the appropriate APIs of your chosen Cloud provider.
   Also you can take a look at services such as Travis.ci, Circle.ci, and others, which might help you created automated testing pipe without the need to spend too much time on the plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

I really like docker's ease of use via the Dockerfile. The Dockerfile let's you very easily update and control the software in the docker image, and then you can provision it in you CI/testing environment. Docker now has native Windows support, so this shouldn't prevent you from being able to use it: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/ Furthermore, I like that you can setup very lightweight, minimal machines, with only the build and runtime dependencies needed for your project, and store them for free on hub.docker.com. Depending on how long it takes to build & install certain dependencies, this can speed up your testing because you can just download a docker image with everything already installed and built, and then just build and test your actual project.

I use this for https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/opencoarrays, which is GCC's official implementation of Coarray Fortran. I have a little project https://github.com/zbeekman/nightly-docker-rebuild that lets you setup nightly docker image builds on hub.docker.com in under two minutes. I use this to trigger builds of https://github.com/zbeekman/nightly-gcc-trunk-docker-image because I can't rebuild GCC from source on Travis-CI.org without the build timing out. This way, I delegate the GCC nightly build to hub.docker.com and then just `docker pull` `zbeekman/nightly-gcc-trunk-docker-image` into a travis-ci instance to test OpenCoarrays against the latest GCC trunk.